# Spring RequestMapping with a regular expression for all levels

Tags: java, spring, request-mapping

Let's say I need to map requests which don't have `.` to add a suffix for them, for example:

```
/a
/a/b
/a/b/c
```

but not

```
/a.html
/a/b.html
/a/b/c.html
```

I am able to map it with a a particular level, with something like the below, but that means a new mapping for each level, and I don't think this is the correct way.

I tried to use `/**` but then how to handle the values which I am not interested it (e.g. the ones with `.`?

```java
@Controller
public class HtmlController {

  @RequestMapping("/{page:^[^.]*$}")
  public String oneLevel(@PathVariable("page") String page) {
    return '/' + page + ".html";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/{first}/{page:^[^.]*$}")
  public String twoLevels(@PathVariable("first") String first, @PathVariable("page") String page) {
    return '/' + first + '/' + page + ".html";
  }

 ...
}
```

Comment: can you try  this --> ^[^\.]*$

Comment: @JavaLearner1 thanks, but it doesn't work, and IntelliJ hints that `Redundant character escape '\\.' in RegExp`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use an interceptor that extends `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and in the `preHandle` method of it, you can reject all the requests which contain '.' in their URLs

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't about rejecting the requests, but rather change the location of some of the requests. In other words, I don't think in `preHandle` one can change the request URI.